# Static class derive from base change member

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, overriding

In C# a static class can not derive from any other class besides object. 
Currently I have this base class:

```
public static class BaseModule
{
    public static string UsedSource {get; set;}

    public static Write(string text)
    {
        OtherStaticClass.Log(UsedSource, text);
    }
}
```

Now, depending on which class I'm using, I want to change `UsedSource`.

```
// this does not work
internal static class ModuleA : BaseModule
{
    static ModuleA(){
        UsedSource = "A" // just an example
    }
}

// this does not work
internal static class ModuleB : BaseModule
{
    static ModuleB(){
        UsedSource = "B" // just an example
    }
}
```

Supposed to be called like this

```
ModuleA.Write("Hi");
ModuleB.Write("Hi");
```

This approach does not work because a static class cannot derive from anything else than object. 
Is there any other way to change the property?

Comment: Why you use static classes at all if you want inheritance features?

Comment: What if you use both modules?

Comment: @TimSchmelter The class is stateless and just provides functionality 'as it is'. The only context is ```UsedSource```. I also don't want to pass that argument as an parameter every time because of the frequent calls.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Both modules are in a different project, they won't be referenced at the same time in the same asssembly. However, both modules reference the core, which implements the base class.

Comment: With your code, are you aware that if you use both ModuleA and ModuleB, the last one to get initialized "wins", after that "both" will say either "A" or "B"?

Comment: A static field exists once, if you change it first to "A" and then to "B", it will stay with "B", even if you use it through ModuleA.

Comment: This is an excellent choice for the singleton pattern. Look into that instead.

Comment: @Shawn you can try to use a static ctor to initialize `UsedSource` in each `Module`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen If I got that correctly, changing the value of ModuleA in Assembly A and later changing the value of ModuleB int Assembly B results in 'overwriting' the value of ModuleA?

Comment: Yes, because in reality there is no "value of ModuleA", there's only the value in BaseModule. You don't get a separate field in ModuleA, it's the same field.

Comment: This is why inheritance of static classes isn't allowed, **it doesn't make sense**.

Comment: You could just have one static class with two methods `WriteA` and `WriteB`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of static classes going on here and I'm not entirely sure they're necessary.  My example does not use static classes other than for the `OtherStaticClass` reference you have.  I understand this may not be quite what you're looking for; many ways to skin this cat.

```
public abstract class BaseModule
{
    public string UsedSource { get; set; }

    public void Write(string text)
    {
        OtherStaticClass.Log(UsedSource, text);
    }   
}

public class ModuleA : BaseModule
{
    public ModuleA()
    {
        UsedSource = "A";
    }   
}

public class ModuleB : BaseModule
{
    public ModuleB()
    {
        UsedSource = "B";
    }
}
```

To get your output then, you just need to create new instances of `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`.

```
var moduleA = new ModuleA();
var moduleB = new ModuleB();
moduleA.Write("Hi");
moduleB.Write("Hi");
```

Comment: Then you can create the instance at the entry point and pass it into the contractor of the classes that need it.  This approach shouldn't solve the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using a static class means using a singleton. Singletons defeat the purpose of tracking the effective dependencies of your classes.

Anyway, you can approach the problem by refactoring your code and using a factory:

In this case, just drop the `static` keyword and let the class be inheritable (you have to add the appropriate `virtual` keywords to allow proper inheritance):

```
public class BaseModule
{
    public string UsedSource {get; set;}

    public Write(string text)
    {
        OtherStaticClass.Log(UsedSource, text);
    }
}
```

Then, add an additional class which holds the reference (I gave useless names, focus on the purpose):

```
public static class MySingleton
{
    public static BaseModule _Module;

    public static BaseModule Module
    {
        get
        {
            return _Module;
        }
    }

    public static void ChangeImplementation (BaseModule module)
    {
        // do your checks here

        _Module = module;
    }
}
```

This way wou can achieve what you ask.

As you can see, this code has several issues, among them it's important to note that this code has *global side effects* and is not *thread safe*.

A better approach is to have drop the singleton entirely, and pass the `BaseModule` class (that can be inherited) as an argument of methods/constructors when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you need more than one static class.  Instead separate the logic into methods in one static class.

```
public static class Module
{   
    private const string SourceA = "A";
    private const string SourceB = "B";

    public static WriteA(string text)
    {
        Write(SourceA, text);
    } 

    public static WriteB(string text)
    {
        Write(SourceB, text);
    } 

    private static Write(string source, string text)
    {
        OtherStaticClass.Log(source, text);
    }
}
```

Then instead of

```
ModuleA.Write("Hi");
ModuleB.Write("Hi");
```

you'd do

```
Module.WriteA("Hi");
Module.WriteB("Hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the **BaseModule** class, you can use it with other state and recover state after using:

```
public static class BaseModule
{
    public static string UsedSource {get; set;}

    public static Write(string text)
    {
        OtherStaticClass.Log(UsedSource, text);
    }
}

internal class Writer : IDisposable
{
    string _lastSource;

    public Writer(string source)
    {
        _lastSource = BaseModule.UsedSource;
        BaseModule.UsedSource = source;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        BaseModule.UsedSource = _lastSource;
    }
}

internal abstract class Module
{
    public abstract Source { get; };

    public void Write(string text)
    {
        using (var writer = new Writer(Source))
        {
            BaseModule.Write(text);
        }
    }   
}   

internal class ModuleA : Module
{   
    public override Source => "A";
}

internal class ModuleB : Module
{   
    public override Source => "B";
}
```

But you must ensure thread safety.

If you **can** change the **BaseModule** class:

```
public static class BaseModule
{    
    public static Write(string text, string source)
    {
        OtherStaticClass.Log(source, text);
    }
}

internal abstract class Module
{
    public abstract Source { get; };

    public void Write(string text)
    {       
        BaseModule.Write(text, Source);     
    }   
}   

internal class ModuleA : Module
{   
    public override Source => "A";
}

internal class ModuleB : Module
{   
    public override Source => "B";
}
```